# NSSortDescriptor sorting on properties that could be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have a collection of beacons reporting their distances and I am working in a project with established architecture that I can't change, otherwise i might have the option for different approaches.

There is an existing array of beacon objects that report their average distances. The existing code sorts the array of beacons on their average distance, stored in a property called `_averageDistance`. Everything works well until an offline beacon reports a nil `_averageDistance` indicating that it is not available.

The currentcode is as follows:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOnDistance = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"averageDistance" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOnDistance];
NSArray* sortedBeacons = [allBeacons sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

BOOL sameBeacon = NO;
if(![[sortedBeacons firstObject] isEqual:_closestBeacon]){
    _closestBeacon = (PTBeacon*)[sortedBeacons firstObject];
}
else {
    sameBeacon = YES;
}
```

Is there a way to control the way nil values are handled when sorting an NSArray? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different sorting method to force the unavailable beacons to the end:

```
[allBeacons sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(PTBeacon * firstBeacon, PTBeacon * secondBeacon){
    if( ![firstBeacon averageDistance] ){
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return [[firstBeacon averageDistance] compare:[secondBeacon averageDistance]];
    }
}];
```

This makes any beacon whose `averageDistance` is `nil` compare greater than any other beacon, which is the opposite of what's currently happening. The unavailable beacons will end up (in arbitrary order amongst themselves) past any other beacon in the sorted array.

Or you could filter the array before sorting:

```
NSPredicate * availabilityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"averageDistance != NIL"];
NSArray * allAvailableBeacons = [allBeacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:availabilityPredicate];
```

This will result in `allAvailableBeacons` containing only beacons whose `averageDistance` is not `nil`. You then sort that array instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom `NSSortDescriptor` to handle the nil values as you see fit:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOnDistance = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"averageDistance"
                                            ascending:YES
                                           comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)  {
                                               if(obj1 == nil){
                                                    //customize here
                                                    return NSOrderedDescending;
                                               }else if(obj2 == nil){
                                                    return NSOrderedAscending;
                                               }else{  
                                                    return [obj1 compare:obj2];}
                                               }];
```